# Convert video to .bin for hologram 3D fan

Tags: c#, video, bin

I am facing the issue where I need to convert a video(in .mp4 for example) to .bin so it can be read by one of these infamous 3D Holographic Fan. At the moment I am doing it this way using C#.

```
private async Task<bool> convertToBin(string file)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file);
        string path = Path.GetFullPath(file) + ".bin";
        string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, str);
        return true;
    }
```

However, the produced .bin is recognized by the fan but when played the LEDs all turn white. Furthermore if I open a .bin generated with the fan's software the format seems completely different, as the first 8.000 lines of the correct .bin are just 0000 0000 0000 0000.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: You are not converting anything, you are just, and only, changing the extension of the file while assuming the original file was encoded with UTF8. I highly doubt that's true for any kind of video.

Comment: Which video format are you using? what encoding? 
Anyways - the right approach would be to read its bytes and then write them into a new .bin file

Comment: Have you tried to use Unity? Check this: [How to compress and decompress binary streams in Unity](http://www.sebaslab.com/how-to-compress-and-decompress-binary-stream-in-unity/)

Comment: Can you convert a test image like [this **one**](https://codropspz-tympanus.netdna-ssl.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/TextFill_image3.png) to `.bin`? Share a link to the converted bin file and tell us details of expected (3D fan's) display resolution? It's possible that `.bin` is just RGB data.

Comment: I have also been trying to achieve something similar. I'm not too worried about changing the file extension to `.bin` obviously, but it would be great to know what exact video codec needs to be used for these things, so I can encode videos using ffmpeg instead of the silly software they provide (Windows only, yuck). Of course no proper documentation seems to be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question on file conversion since technically you can just change the extension on any file to .bin and it is a valid .bin file.

The reason being that the .bin extension has no specific standard, its just a collection of binary data - this means that different companies can (if they wish) implement their own standards within files that they work with.

In terms of holo fans, most manufacturers of them will often either have for free (or a small fee) a video conversion piece of software available that converts a file into a .bin that will work with the fan for you. (also many fans now can just work with .mp4 etc too, but im guessing yours cant)

If the first X amount of data in the correct file really is just a stream of 0's it seems as if there is some amount of "padding" at the beginning of the file though without really being able to see the file not 100% on that.

Either way, generic conversion to a .bin without knowing the specific format that the device / manufacturer is potentially enforcing is pretty hard - like trying to get the exact amount of water to fill a bucket, without ever seeing the bucket

> Binary itself is meaningless, until such time as an executed algorithm defines what should be done with each bit, byte, word or block. Thus, just examining the binary and attempting to match it against known formats can lead to the wrong conclusion as to what it actually represents.

Quote from the Wiki page on Binary files :)